# Why are my NSMenuItem items greyed out?

Tags: cocoa, nsmenuitem

I have an app pictured below:

[image]

But I want the greyed out fields (Computer Name, Private IP, DNS IP and Last Update) to be black like the fields below them. I have tried changing the targets as suggestion on SO but it doesn't seem to make a difference. These items are not clickable and are just there to show data.

I can make a bunch of empty IBActions for them and that works but it doesn't seem like the correct way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: It means they are dimmed and therefore they are not enable.

Comment: They say they are enabled in the inspector.

Comment: How can I make them not dimmed?

Comment: You shouldn't. Thats how the UI it is meant to be

Comment: Hmmm looks ugly. I will just create an empty single IBAction and link the 4 greyed out to it.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: You may not set any action to that MenuItems so they are grey out.

```
[item setAction: @selector(noAction:)]; 
-(void)noAction:(id)sender{
// Simply do nothing here
}
```

Option 2: Set customView with textField to that MenuItems.